# PromQL: Get Time delay difference between current time() and from a custom_metric_time in a app

Tags: python, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I have an exporter that exports the start time/last sync time of an app in epoch format. I need to compare this with the current time() metric in Prometheus, also in epoch format. If the gap between the current time and the start time/last sync time is more than 12 hours, I need to trigger an alert by resulting value (possibly a boolean). How can I achieve this? I have tried a few comparison operators, but they didn't work. This is the code I have tried so far:

```
vector(time()) - on () 43200 < (custom_gauge_exporter_in_app{job="python-app"})
```

Answer (score 0):

To create such an alert you can use expression

```
time() - custom_gauge_exporter_in_app{job="python-app"} > 43200
```

`time()` returns scalar value, so no need for vector matching there.

Also, your alert will have all the labels of `custom_gauge_exporter_in_app` metric, and value of difference between current time and value of said metric (in seconds)

If you want to add to descriptions something like "Last backup was N hours ago", you can use following:

```yaml
  - alert: Backut_too_old
    expr: floor((time() - custom_gauge_exporter_in_app{job="python-app"})/60/60) >= 12
    annotations:
      summary: Backup is too old
      description: Last backup was {{ $value }} hours ago
```